Eliminating the Parameter and Implicit/Explicit Preservation of Constraints
Suppose we have the following two equations to represent a curve:
$$
x = e^{-2t}
$$
$$
y = e^{3t}
$$
I am asked to eliminate the parameter. My instinct was to raise both equations by a power to achieve the least common multiple:
$$
x^3 = \left(e^{-2t}\right)^{3} = e^{-6t}
$$
$$
y^{-2} = \left(e^{3t}\right)^{-2} = e^{-6t}
$$
I can then set the equations equal:
$$
x^3 = y^{-2}
$$
At first, I thought that this was the correct answer. However, I noticed an issue. If we go back to the original parameterized equations, we see that both x and y can only take on values $(0, +\infty)$, but my current equation allows $ y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and in particular $y \in (-\infty, 0) $. In this case, I can solve this issue by either solving for y in my equation and taking only the positive root or manually noting that x and y values are constrained to $(0, +\infty)$.
While I guess these solutions work, they require careful attention and knowledge of the function's graph. More than anything, this situation highlights a larger concern. Namely, I feel I am not eliminating the parameter correctly if I have to explicitly/manually constrain the values of my resulting equation. Are there generalized heuristics to avoid this manual constraining? Are there ways of eliminating the parameter that implicitly preserves the restrictions imposed by the parameter?

I guess the problem is raising $e^{-3t}$ to the power of $2$, which is even. It's something like $x=4 \implies x^2 = 16$ which has the new solution $x=-4$

I see. In the same way, we could take a different approach by solving for $e^t$ in both equations. This time, the square rooting required in the x equation will also introduce additional solutions. It seems fair to say that I should avoid raising equations by even powers or rooting by even root indices.

Square rooting should work. Why do you say it introduces additional solutions?

Anyway, let me point out that in your first approach $ x^3 = \left(\frac{1}{y} \right)^2$, so actually $x^3 >0 \implies x>0$

Suppose we have $x = \frac{1}{e^{2t}}$. If we isolate for $e^t$, we must raise both sides by $\frac{-1}{2}$. But $\sqrt{e^{2t}} = |e^{t}|$, introducing the same issue as raising by a power of 2.

As for the second response, I struggle to understand why the stated implication is relevant. Do you mean that my equation does contain the desired constraint? If so, how? @DavideMasi

Note that $|e^t| = e^t$. Also I meant that you claimed "but my current equation allows for $\mathbb{R} /{0}$ values for both", while the problem is only on $y$

Thank you. I see my misunderstanding. $e^t$ is necessarily greater than zero.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
